# Send email alerts from Nlog for specific exceptions

Tags: email, nlog, alerts

I am working on configuring `NLog` configuration which works perfectly for logging into text files. Now on the top of this I want to set a conditional target as `Mail` which should get fired only for a specific set of exceptions. For example - if there is a `PaymentFailedException`, `CardExpiredException` then the `NLog` should target `Mail`.
I have checked the `NLog` documentation but I could not find any way to set it for specific set of exceptions. However, `NLog` allows for setting target as `Mail` for exception levels.

Answer (score 2):

You could configure use the `<when>` for this.

e.g.

```xml
<logger name="*" writeTo="myMailTarget">
  <filters>
    <when condition="not contains('${exception:format=type}', 'PaymentFailedException") action="Ignore" />
  </filters>
</logger>
```

See [filtering log messages](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages) and [`<when>` docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-filter)